# Drawing triangles and squares with C

Tags: c, shapes

I have to draw a triangle on the square with asterisk
the expected output as the image below.

Instruction is this: Write a C program that reads a number n from the user and allows to print a house
with a roof using ‘*’ characters. The house should be a n x n square and the roof two
diagonal lines of 45 degrees forming a roof (if n is odd the roof closes in the top perfectly). 
I create a triangle and square but i can't combine them. Triangle

```
    {
    int i,j,k,x,h=0;
    printf("\n\n");

    for( i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for( k = 1; k <=5-i; k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("*");
        for( j = 2; j <= 2*i-2; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        if(i>1) printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
    for ( i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
            printf("* ");
    }


    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show the expected output in your question instead of providing a reference.

Comment: i did with image link. it is what to expect. if user enter 7 write the first one for example.

Comment: well, YOU also need to show the output from the posted code, with some explanation of what is wrong with it.   BTW: were it the literal `5` entering into the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you may discovered that you need to have two cases: `n` is odd or `n` is even.

Then if `n` is odd, you need to iterate `1+(n-1)/2` times, and if `n` is even, `n/2` times, to print the `^` shape.

After you printed a shape like `^`, you need to print a line with `n` `'*'`s.

Then you need to iterate `n-2` times, and print a line with a `'*'`, `n-2` `' '`s and another `'*'` each time.

Finally print a line with `n` `'*'`s.

Try to convert each sentence into a block of c code and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Some tricky code in this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int width = 8;
    char stars[width];
    memset(stars, '*', width);

    printf((width%2)? "%*s\n" : "", (width+1)/2, "*");
    for(int i=0; i< (width)/2; ++i)
    {
        printf("%*s%*s\n", (width+1)/2-i-(width%2), "*", 2*(i+1) - !(width%2), "*");
    }
    printf("%.*s\n", width, stars);
    for(int i=0; i<width-2; ++i)
    {
        printf("*%*s\n", width-1, "*");
    }
    printf("%.*s\n", width, stars);
    return 0;
}
```

### Sample Output, with `width` as `7` and `8`:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4264KB
   *
  * *
 *   *
*     *
*******
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
*******

Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4356KB
   **
  *  *
 *    *
*      *
********
*      *
*      *
*      *
*      *
*      *
*      *
********
```

Comment: it's great. i appreciate your efford.